# Is there a way to fuzzy match phrases but have exact matches on numbers/digits?

Tags: python-3.x, fuzzy-comparison

I'm trying to find cases where I have an input and a param and I have to see if they match, but I want to take into account normalization and just general variations in speech. For example, I have a param that is ["feb. 19th"] and the user input is "February 19th" I want to be able to match that, while being able to detect that an input that says "February 18th" is incorrect. This would be in python if that's helpful. I'm trying to figure out the method before writing the actual code.